# Generate random number without repetition between two numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a number from 0 to 10 randomly using JavaScript and each number can appear only once. Is there a possibility

Comment: What've you tried yourself?

Comment: When you say you want to generate *a* random number which can only appear once, do you mean to want to generate several? And stop on a repeat? Or have the numbers 0..10 in a random permuation? Or something else?

Comment: Actually numbers in row from 0 to 10 **is** random and does not repeats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution :

HTML :

```
<button onclick="getNumber()">click</button>
```

JS :

```
var number = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function getNumber() {
    if (0 === number.length) {
        alert('Finish')
    } else {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * number.length);
        alert(number[index]);
        number.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, perhaps badly expressed but I want to get the effect of generating a random number between 1 and 10 and not to duplicate to display all ten numbers.

Comment: Don't understand, you only want that the script generate a number between 1 and 10. That's all ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = []

// 6 is max length of num taken, change it to your convenience

while (arr.length < 6) {
    Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

    // console.log(Random);
    
    let indexValue = arr.indexOf(Random);
    console.log(Random, indexValue);

    if (indexValue == -1) {
        arr.push(Random);
    }
}

console.log(arr);

// the code will push numbers between 0 to 5 without repetition
// into an empty array
```